# Binding function keys in carbon-emacs

Tags: carbon-emacs

While I was using the "normal" X11 emacs under Snow Leopard, my profile.el file had a line:

```
    (global-set-key [f14] 'my_function)
```

However this binding does not work with carbon-emacs. What is strange is that if I execute the command "M-x global-set-key", and give it the right arguments (pressing the F14 key), it works!

Any hints?

-- Tsf

Comment: Using the fink build of carbon-emacs22 it works as expected. (Well, I have a MacBook, thus no f14, and I tested it with f6.)

Answer (score 1):

My line

```
   (global-set-key [f14] 'my_function)
```

was in an auxiliary profile.el file loaded by the command

```
   (load "profile")
```

in my .emacs file.  When I moved it to the .emacs file itself, it worked!  As a matter of fact the same happened with another definition I was having troubles with:

```
   (setq visible-bell t)
```

used to disable unpleasant sounds.

-- Tsf

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the normal gnu emacs for mac, probably from one of the vanilla builds..., and [f14] works fine for me... why are you using a non-standard emacs?

Granted, i'm using emacs 22, so maybe things changed, but I doubt it...

Comment: I think carbon-emacs is better integrated with Mac OS X.

-- tsf